# Full rights on new files created on mounted partition

Tags: linux, mount, file-permissions

I have created a new partition (ext4) on a 4tb disk and i want to use that partition to store media.
Is it possible to mount that partition and set full rights to new files created by various users? And if yes, how?

Note: I want to do this for future data, not existing data.

Comment: Do you want different rights for different users, or the same right for all users?

Comment: Same rights for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, files do not inherit permissions from directories by default. You need to use a recursive Access Control List for that.

Let's say you have a directory called 'ACL_dir' you want to apply these changes to. That is, you want all users' new files to be world-readable and world-writable. You can do this by executing the following commands:

```
setfacl -d -m o::rwx ACL_dir
setfacl -d -m g::rwx ACL_dir
```

When you now place a new file in this directory, it is as if 'chmod o+rw FILE' is done on it automatically. (Also 'chmod g+rw FILE', as you can see above.) If you now call 'ls -l' in above the directory, you'll note that instead of something like 'drwxr-xr-x' for the permissions it now says 'drwxr-xr-x+'. The '+' means that an ACL is now active for that directory.

You may also want to check out the 'setfacl' and 'getfacl' man pages.

Comment: Thanks Robin. I've made a test and after i copied a file in that test folder the new file still retained the old permissions. If an ACL is applied to the parent directory, it will take precedence over the file's permissions?

Comment: Just made a test now and changed the copied file's permission and owner and looks like the ACL permissions are taken into account. Thanks Robin for the solution

Comment: A quick qestion: will this work for folders too? Or just files?

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether it works for directories inside directories as well. You may need to change the '-d' into an '-R' for that. (Since I couldn't test this myself right now, please be careful and try it on a dummy folder structure first.)

Comment: I've used both -d and -R and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <mount point>
```

Make sure you get the mount point correct, triple check it.

Comment: This will fix only existing data on the mount point. I want to know how can all future data created on the mount point will be automatically set to 777